# Mouse hover triggers hover on itself and another div

Tags: html, css, hover

I am trying to set something up where when someone hovers over `.twitter-underline-1` it triggers the `:hover` for that class AND the `:hover` for the `#twitter-1` id

vice verse

When someone hovers over `#twitter-1` it triggers the `:hover` for that id AND the `:hover` for the `.twitter-underline-1` class

I tried some recommended solutions from other who asked a similar question but nothing fully worked. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```css
.twitter-underline-1 {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #E0E0E0;
}
.twitter-underline-1:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4099FF;
}
#twitter-1 {
  padding-top: 402px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #E0E0E0;
  margin-left: 45px;
}
#twitter-1:hover {
  color: #4099FF;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<span class="twitter-underline-1">Blah blah text</span>

<div class="twitter">
  <span title="Click to Tweet"><i id="twitter-1" class="fa fa-twitter"></i></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit abhitalks.

Comment: not possible to select previous sibling you can use jQuery or javascript

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes Can you point me in the right direction of a jQuery solution?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3855n719/ trigger hover using jquery

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes That did exactly what I needed! You are the man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/3855n719/

```
$('#twitter-1').hover(
  function() {
    $('.twitter-underline-1').addClass('hover');
  },
  function() {
    $('.twitter-underline-1').removeClass('hover');
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done without changing your html structure as it is impossible to select a previous element in css.

I think you have two options:

1. Surround it with a `.twitter-container` and add the `:hover` class there. This might only be an option if you don't have any other content between the `.twitter-underline` and `#twitter-1` as hovering over them would also add the styling.
2. Move the `.twitter-underline` element in the html below the `#twitter-1`, select it with a 
   sibling selector like `+` or `~` and use `position: absolute` to put it back in its proper place.

**Example for method 1**

```css
.twitter-underline-1 {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #E0E0E0;
}

#twitter-1 {
  padding-top: 402px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #E0E0E0;
  margin-left: 45px;
}

.twitter-container:hover .twitter-underline-1 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4099FF;  
}

.twitter-container:hover #twitter-1 {
  color: #4099FF;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="twitter-container">
  <span class="twitter-underline-1">Blah blah text</span>

  <div class="twitter">
    <span title="Click to Tweet"><i id="twitter-1" class="fa fa-twitter"></i></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Example for method 2**

```css
.twitter-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 1em;
}
.twitter-underline-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #E0E0E0;
}
#twitter-1 {
  padding-top: 402px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #E0E0E0;
  margin-left: 45px;
}
#twitter-1:hover {
  color: #4099FF;
}
#twitter-1:hover + .twitter-underline-1 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4099FF;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="twitter-container">
  <div class="twitter">
    <span title="Click to Tweet">
      <i id="twitter-1" class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
      <span class="twitter-underline-1">Blah blah text</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually as you want to have both I think only method would work. If that isn't enough indeed use jQuery to add/remove a `.active` class on both elements